# Creating a lot of numbered URLs easily

Tags: python, html, django

I have a list of Hospitals on a web page and each Hospital has a link with it that should open a new page which shows all the reviews and feedbacks that people fill in the feedback form. The problem is that the list goes on for about 70-80 hospitals and creating a URL and a view for each one is a very tiring and long job. Also the number of hospitals may vary later on and then that new entry would require a new URL and view. I want to know if there's any easy way to create those 80 URLs without having to actually create even those 80 URLs (like maybe a loop or something). I'm very new to Django, Python and HTML so an easily understandable way is much appreciated. I'm using PyCharm community and Python 3 for this project. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why would you need to create a URL and view for each one? Why wouldn't you create a single URL that passes a parameter to the view?

Comment: create one view which gets hospital's number or its name and use it to display different content. Doc: [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Yes thank you! That solves my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Django URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/). You can define a single URL with a pattern in it. For example, the pattern could be pk of the `Hospital` instance.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('reviews/<int:hospital_pk>/', views.hospital_reviews, name='hospital-reviews'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models    

class Hospital(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Review(models.Model):
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Hospital

def hospital_reviews(request, hospital_pk):
    hospital = Hospital.objects.get(pk=hospital_pk)
    return render(request, 'reviews.html', {'reviews': hospital.review_set.all()})
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me the solution in detail!